# Google Docs: Table of content page numbers

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api, google-document-viewer

we are currently building an application on  the google cloud platform, which generates reports in Google Doc. For them, it is really important to have a table of content ... with page numbers. I know this is a feature request since a few years and there are add-ons (Paragraph Styles +, which didn't work for us) that provide this solution, butt we are considering to build this ourselves. if anybody has a suggestion on how we could start with this, it would be a great help!

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Best bet is to file a feature request on the product forums.

Currently the only way to do that level of manipulation of a doc to provide a custom TOC is to use Apps Script. It provides access to the document structure sufficient enough to build and insert a basic table of contents, but I'm not sure there's enough to do paging correctly (unless you force a page break on ever page...) There's no method to answer the question of "what page is this element on?"

Hacks like writing to a DOCX and converting don't work because TOCs are recognized for what they and show up without page numbers.

Of course you could write a DOCX or PDF with the TOC as you'd like and upload as a blob rather than as a Google Doc. They can still be viewed in Drive and such.

Comment: Hi steve, thanks for the suggestion. indeed, if we had a method to answer that question, it would give us a proper scenario to work out (hello Google? :) ). as we would want to remain within the Google doc (other actions are done within it), the blob- scenario is also not applicable for our case. 

we try to look for another solution (feel free to make suggestions) and let you know  once we got something to work with!